# Obtener registro con la fecha mas reciente

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

Tengo un metodo donde obtengo un registro de puertas dependiendo del `ID` del usuario y del `ID` de la orden activa que tiene ese usuario. La orden puede tener varias puertas pero la puerta solo puede pertenecer a una orden, y el usuario puede tener varias ordenes pero en diferentes estados (Activa, inactiva). Todo esto ya implementado.

Lo que quiero hacer es almacenar en el `ViewBag.xUserDoors` el registro de la puerta con la fecha mas reciente o el ultimo registro que tiene esa orden activa.

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {

            BusinessLogic.lnDoorsxUser _LN = new BusinessLogic.lnDoorsxUser();
            var xDoorsU = _LN.GetAllDoorsxUser();
            var doorByOrder = xDoorsU.Where(x => x.Order.Id == OrderUserId ).FirstOrDefault();
            ViewBag.xUserDoors = doorByOrder;
            return View();                         

    }
```

Comment: de donde sale el valor de `OrderUserId ` ?

Comment: De una consulta realizada anterior, Esta en el mismo metodo pero solo coloque en el post la parte del codigo donde queria aplicar el ordenamiento. Muchas gracias Leandro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podrias ordenar de forma descendente por el `campo fecha` para tener la ultima registrada, entonces tomas esa unicamente

```
var doorByOrder = xDoorsU.Where(x => x.Order.Id == OrderUserId )
                            .OderByDescending(x=>x.Fecha)
                            .FirstOrDefault();
```